Universal property of the Clifford algebra
Let $E$ be a finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{K}$ and let $g: E \times E \rightarrow \mathbb{K}$ be a symmetric bilinear form on $E$.
A Clifford algebra for $g$ is an algebra denoted $C_g(E)$ together with a linear map $\rho:E \rightarrow C_g(E)$ such that $\forall x \in E: \ \rho(x)^2 = g(x,x) \cdot 1_{C_g(E)}$ with the following universal property: If $\psi: E \rightarrow L$ is a linear map of $E$ into an algebra $L$ such that
\begin{align}
    \forall x \in E: \quad \psi(x)^2 = g(x,x) \cdot 1_L
  \end{align}
then there exists a unique algebra-homomorphism
\begin{align}
    \tilde{\psi}:C_g(E) \rightarrow L
  \end{align}
such that $\tilde{\psi}\circ\rho=\psi$.
I've seen some texts leave out the condition: $\forall x \in E: \ \rho(x)^2 = g(x,x) \cdot 1_{C_g(E)}$ (it should probably follow from the universal property), but I can't see how right now, I'd be happy for some help:)

It does not "follow from the universal property", it is part of the data; it is more proper to say that the arrow $E \to C_g(E)$ is a universal arrow in a particular category.
This arrow typically comes from any concrete definition of $C_g(E)$, which is why it's not necessary to explicitly list its properties.

A side note: your definition of Clifford algebra is nonstandard.
In the case that $\mathbb K$ has characteristic 2 note that
$$
  g(x+y,x+y) - g(x,x) - g(y,y) = 2g(x,y) = 0
$$
so in the Clifford algebra
$$
  \rho(x)\rho(y) + \rho(y)\rho(x) = 0 \implies \rho(x)\rho(y) = \rho(y)\rho(x)
$$
for all $x,y \in E$ and it follows that $C_g(E)$ is commutative.
To avoid this trivialization, a distinction is made between symmetric bilinear forms and quadratic forms, and Clifford algebras are defined in terms of quadratic forms.
